# @RequestBody with MultiValueMap not working in swagger V3 in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Since I upgraded to Open Api/Swagger v3, The @RequestBody with MultiValueMap is not working anymore.

The values which are entered in the swagger UI are not translated/converted correctly in the controller class anymore.

I always get the same default values in the variable "params" (all, empty), instead of the values entered in Swagger UI.  See screenshot of debugging below.

How can I make this work again ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot, you have shown the value Map<String, List<Object>> and in the request, you are expecting Map<String,String>

Comment: The request is what Swagger UI generated.  I've no control on that. With the previous version of Swagger it was exactly the same.